# Why does -g -G result in Cuda error 7: too many resources requested for launch?

Tags: cuda, cpu-registers

I've got a C++ Cuda toolkit v9.2 application that works fine built with `-O`, but if I build with `-g -G`, I get a cuda error 7 at runtime:

> too many resources requested for launch

I understand [from here](http://cuda-programming.blogspot.com/2013/01/handling-cuda-error-messages.html) that this means:

> the number of registers available on the multiprocessor is being exceeded. Reduce the number of threads per block to solve the problem.

I'd rather not reduce the threads per block since it works optimized.  What might I do so that for debug builds I use fewer registers, more in line with optimized?  How can I track down where the extra register use is coming from in my application?

Comment: Debug builds can require more registers than release builds. There is no workaround other than reducing the block size

Comment: I am reasonably sure that it is also possible that a debug build requires more (thread-)local storage than is available by default, so you might want to look into increasing the amount of local memory configured. If the resource is registers (likely), the comment by @talonmies applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also mentioned in the comments above, debug builds typically require more resources due to various reasons.

You can use the [`--maxrregcount`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation-maxrregcount) option or [`__launch_bounds__` qualifier](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#launch-bounds) to set a limit for how many registers the compiler is allowed to used. Do note that turning this knob really just means trading one resource for another. Forcing the compiler to use fewer registers will generally mean it has to spill more. More spills will generally mean increased local memory requirements. In extreme cases, you may run into another limit there…

Comment: It isn't only die to "lack of optimization" -- optimized (in the performance sense) code can use more  registers than unoptimized code. The debugger  build often requires spilling of some banks from local memory to registers so they can be accessed

Comment: @talonmies you're right of course, I removed that bit.